# AlarmManager stops firing Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android

I use AlarmManager to update my clock widget at top of every minute using a broadcast receiver. This is the code I use to set the alarm in widget onEnabled:

```
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, 0, 60000, PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent(context, ReceiverClockUpdate.class), 0));
```

and this code to stop it in onDisabled:

```
am.cancel(PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent(context, ReceiverClockUpdate.class), 0));
```

I have many reports that the clock stops updating after some times (Maybe 1 hour or even 1 day) or it updates with delays. The most reported devices are Galaxy S3, Galaxy S2 and Galaxy Note.

I don't know and have no clues why this happen. Does AlarmManager stops working after some times or there is an Exception in my code which prevents it from working.

Answer (score 0):

use RTC_WAKEUP .. the alarm manager will not fire when the phone is sleep using only RTC, it will only fire the alarm when the phone is wake up, messing up the 60seconds interval.

RTC_WAKEUP will wakeup the phone sleepmode when trigger, not messing up the interval, also, you need to use BOOT_COMPLETED action for your alarm, because when the phone was turned off, it and then turn on, it will not have the alarm setting...

you need to do some algorithm i think, because thats what i do..

if the phone was turned off for 3 mins, then turned on , you need something like

```
if(alarmtime < currenttime)
{
compute how many minutes have passed..
then make a variable of the minute that has passed.

variable = 3;
i = 0;
while(i<3)
{
update the clock one time
i++;
}

}
```

you need to save alarmtime in a storage, preferable SharedPref

UPDATE: 1st code is the alarm, then the second is the service. In this case, the alarm will determine how many minutes have passed, then have the corresponding counter. This code only check until 3 minutes, just add variables via looping or something

```
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
     {   
         PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
         PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "");
         wl.acquire();


         Toast.makeText(context, "A day has passed by.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 

         wl.release();
         context.startService(new Intent(context, MySim.class));

        SharedPreferences a = context.getSharedPreferences("mPref",0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = a.edit();



     }

 public void SetAlarm(Context context)
 {

     //retrieve alarms and getting current time
     SharedPreferences a = context.getSharedPreferences("mPref",0);

     long iFirst = a.getLong("first", System.currentTimeMillis()+(60*1000));
     long iSecond = a.getLong("second", System.currentTimeMillis()+(120*1000));
     long iThird = a.getLong("third", System.currentTimeMillis()+(180*1000));
     long currenttime = System.currentTimeMillis();
     SharedPreferences.Editor editor = a.edit();


     //editor passed =1 ililipat sa checkclassroom sa tunay na game
     //seting passed
     if(currenttime >= iFirst && currenttime < iSecond)
     {
         editor.putInt("passed", 1);
     }
     if(currenttime >= iSecond && currenttime < iThird)
     {
         editor.putInt("passed", 2);
         iFirst = iSecond;

     }
     if(currenttime >= iThird)
     {
         editor.putInt("passed", 3);
         iFirst = iThird;
     }
        editor.commit();




AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);



     Intent i = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
     PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);


     am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC,iFirst,60*1000, pi); 
 }
```

This is the service:

```
             int passed = a.getInt("passed", 1);
            int counter = 1;
            while(counter <= passed)

            {
            //do the updating of the clock
            counter++;
            }

            editor.putLong("first", System.currentTimeMillis()+60 * 1000);
            editor.putLong("second", System.currentTimeMillis()+120 * 1000);
            editor.putLong("third", System.currentTimeMillis()+180 * 1000);
            editor.putInt("passed", 1);
            editor.commit();
        }
```

Comment: First I don't want to turn the device on just for updating the clock. Second the problem is not with boot. It occurs without any restarting or anything.

Comment: you need to use rtc_wakeup to make the alarm still fire even when the phone is sleep, because when the phone sleeps, your alarm wont fire until the phone is woke up.

Comment: See my update answer, it would not wake up the phone but when the phone wokeup, the alarm would do compute and update it as should be. You need to provide the logcat of what could be the problem when it stops firing, it could have exception

Comment: This is exactly how I did it. The problem is alarmanager stops calling the receiver after some time on those mentioned devices. I have an xperia Arc. There is no problem on my device and I don't have access to the logcat of customers device. But I put a exception writer in my code, it seems there is no exception even.

Comment: there should probably an exception, maybe you didnt noticed it. Or maybe the phones terminate your app's alarm in some way, dont know if thats possible.